# Getting a bad request 400 when using Curl -s -v -X POST with ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, post, curl, processbuilder

I am trying to execute the following curl command using ProcessBuilder in Java, however, I am getting a bad request.

Here is the code:

```
// Get all inventory items
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-v", "-X", "POST",
        "https://api.clover.com/v3/merchants/W97HP438A0KSR/items/FEKSZZHF5T43R", "-H",
        "Content-Type: application/json", "-H", "Authorization: Bearer 335d0604-e948-5553-2a7e-7d6e504c6bc6",
        "--data", "{\"price\":8000}");

Process p;
try {
    p = pb.start();
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    InputStream errorStream = p.getErrorStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream));
    String strLine = "";
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(strLine);
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting the following error in the console:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Any help is appreciated.

Fernando

Comment: Did you try to run the `curl` manually ? I get 401... `curl -v -X POST https://api.clover.com/v3/merchants/W97HP438A0KSR/items/FEKSZZHF5T43R -H Content-Type: application/json -H Authorization: Bearer 335d0604-e948-5553-2a7e-7d6e504c6bc6 --data {"price":8000}`

Comment: Never mind.  I just needed to escape double quotes with \"  and escape \" with \\\" .

Comment: Thanks alfasin for your comments.

Comment: Hi alfasin, I did try to run the command curl manually and it worked.  I just forgot to escape double quoutes properly. I.e. change --data {"price":8000} to --data "{\"price\":8000}"

Comment: Great, if that was the case you can delete the question.